# Unable to launch the Jenkins on browser

Tags: jenkins

I Downloaded the war file from the Jenkins site and started on custom port.
"INFO: Jenkins is fully up and running" is shown after running several instructions. But when I tried it on a browser with "http://localhost:port" it is not connecting. It's throwing a message: "the webpage is not available"

My system contain java version 1.6 and the downloaded version of Jenkins is 1.5.

Please let me know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: I think Jenkins is default started on :8080 and not on :port

Comment: Can you provide some more information; are you using windows, linux or a mac.  Did you start Jenkins using the command line or is it installed as a service.  It would also help if you included the log file in your question.

Comment: Am having similar problem on mac and I have tried localhost:8080/jenkins and it returns 404 code. Can someone assist me with this issue pls

Comment: I am also facing the same issue .. I have docker in my system and also installed Jenkins through official site.It was successfully installed however, localhost is not opening in browser I am done all this on Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Niels has already mentioned try this

http://localhost:8080/jenkins

instead of

http://localhost:port

Let us know if this works

Comment: Yes it works, I am running the jenkins on windows machine

Answer (score 1):

I could see this file jenkins.err provide the clear information of error most of the time .

In My Situation , the below issue faced and it worked after resolving it .

Jenkins requires Java versions [8, 11] but you are running with Java 16 from C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: 60.0
at Main.verifyJavaVersion(Main.java:174)
at Main.main(Main.java:142)

Thanks,
Saty

Answer (score 0):

Running jenkins in Docker and unable to access jenkin's landing page via http://localhost:8080?

Check the IP address that Docker configured to use for the default machine. Hence, jenkins is accessible via http://configured-ip:8080

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new inbound rule for Port 8080 in Windows Firwall-->Advance setting.
Once done, try to reload jenkins, it works

Comment: This is what worked for me: an inbound rule for java.exe on port 8080. Caveat, if you add the rule for java.exe in Programs and Services when you upgrade java the path usually changes. You need to edit Jenkins.xml as well as the Inbound rule. For me, the Inbound rule was pointing to `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_271\bin\java.exe` but the upgrade of Java was in `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_311\bin` so the rule broke and we couldn't connect to Jenkins. You'll need to change the path in the inbound rule to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to figure this one out. For me, it started happening after changing my Windows password. The solution was to update the Credentials for Jenkins Service.

1- In Windows search bar, type services then enter.
2- Then scroll down to Jenkins and double-click on it.
3- In Jenkins Properties, select tab "Log On".
4- Select Check box "This account"
5- Update your username and password.

Voila! Now Jenkins web can connect to the Jenkins machine via Jenkins service.

Answer (score 0):

For me Centos 7 firewall was blocking port 8080

`firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=8080/tcp`

`firewall-cmd --reload`